# Flutter how can i make a stateless widget for each element inside a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have a list of strings

List names = ['ahmed','samy','ramy'];

how can i iterate through each element inside the list and make a statless widget like for each one of them using the map function

```
class Names extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('${'names['0']'}');
```

and when the list updated a statless widget will create automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List.builder`:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: names.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return Names(names[index]);
    }
  )
```

and change Names class:

```
class Names extends StatelessWidget {
final String name;
Names(this.name);
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not what i want i updated the answer for more details

Comment: @ewidaa I think this is exactly what you want.. you just don't know it

Comment: @ewidaa It will rerender when list updated. You have to set your list as state in stateful widget.